# How to find the right fitness class?

Tags: gym

There are many fitness clubs and centers in my city area. 
How to choose the most appropriate option for me ?

At this point I don't really know what is the most important to ask for regarding fitness clubs.

**Edit:**

Thank you for all your comments. Let me reformulate my question then:

**What questions should I ask myself before I can decide on the right fitness class  ?**

Comment: Well that kind of depends on what your goals are, care to share those with us?

Comment: Visit them and see if they offer what you believe you want?

Comment: The answers won't matter if you don't know what you want. Why do you want to join a fitness club?

Comment: In general I would like to start a habit of exercising regularly, to build up self discipline and to become more fit and vital.

Comment: Not specific enough. It's like asking how to find the right job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an article on that subject on [www.medicinenet.com](http://www.medicinenet.com/script/main/art.asp?articlekey=46413).

[The article](http://www.medicinenet.com/script/main/art.asp?articlekey=46413) suggests 10 questions one should ask in order to decide on the right class:

1. What are the instructor's qualifications and training?
2. Where and
   when is the class held?
3. What type of exercise activity interests you
   the most?
4. Is it possible to attend a variety of classes?
5. How crowded
   is the class?
6. Can you observe a class or take a trial class for free
   before you commit?
7. How does the instructor interact with
   participants?
8. What are the costs of the class?
9. What are the
   facilities like?
10. Is the class fun?

Any other ideas ?